# How import function from C++ inside Cython class?

Tags: python, c++, cython

I'm learning Cython and I'm trying to define a class that uses a C++ function that I created. After almost two days reading docs and trying I Always have an error. This is the **error trace**:

```
/home/rubiales/Desktop/Projects/General/venv-General/compiler_compat/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/random.o: in function `int std::uniform_int_distribution<int>::operator()<std::mersenne_twister_engine<unsigned long, 32ul, 624ul, 397ul, 31ul, 2567483615ul, 11ul, 4294967295ul, 7ul, 2636928640ul, 15ul, 4022730752ul, 18ul, 1812433253ul> >(std::mersenne_twister_engine<unsigned long, 32ul, 624ul, 397ul, 31ul, 2567483615ul, 11ul, 4294967295ul, 7ul, 2636928640ul, 15ul, 4022730752ul, 18ul, 1812433253ul>&, std::uniform_int_distribution<int>::param_type const&)':
/home/rubiales/Desktop/Projects/Route_optimizer/MTSPTW/algorithm/cython/GA/random.cpp:14: multiple definition of `_randuniform()'; build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/test_class.o:/home/rubiales/Desktop/Projects/Route_optimizer/MTSPTW/algorithm/cython/GA/random.cpp:14: first defined here
/home/rubiales/Desktop/Projects/General/venv-General/compiler_compat/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/random.o: in function `_randint(int, int)':
/home/rubiales/Desktop/Projects/Route_optimizer/MTSPTW/algorithm/cython/GA/random.cpp:22: multiple definition of `_randint(int, int)'; build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/test_class.o:/home/rubiales/Desktop/Projects/Route_optimizer/MTSPTW/algorithm/cython/GA/random.cpp:22: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'g++' failed with exit status 1
```

The main part of this error trace I think is:

```
multiple definition of `_randuniform()' first defined here
```

**This is my Cython class:** `test_class.pyx`:

```
# random_builder.pyx
# distutils: language = c++
# distutils: sources = random.cpp
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
import cython

cdef extern from "random.cpp":
    cdef float _randuniform()
    cdef int _randint(int min_val, int max_val)


cdef class RandomClass():
    cdef:
        int a, b
    def __init__(self, int a, int b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    cpdef float randf(self):
        return _randuniform()

    cpdef int randi(self):
        return _randint(self.a, self.b)
```

The two C++ functions: `random.cpp`

```
#ifndef RANDOM_CPP
#define RANDOM_CPP
#include <Python.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <numeric>


using namespace std;

float _randuniform(){
    std::random_device rand_dev;
    std::mt19937 generator(rand_dev());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<float>  distr(0, 1);

    return distr(generator);
}

int _randint(int min_val, int max_val){
    std::random_device rd;     // only used once to initialise (seed) engine
    std::mt19937 rng(rd());    // random-number engine used (Mersenne-Twister in this case)
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uni(min_val,max_val); // guaranteed unbiased

    int random_integer = uni(rng);
    return random_integer;
}

#endif
```

And the file: `setup.py`

```
from setuptools import Extension, setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules = cythonize(Extension(
           "test_class",                                # the extension name
           sources=["test_class.pyx", "random.cpp"], # the Cython source and
                                                  # additional C++ source files
           language="c++",                        # generate and compile C++ code
      )))
```

The cpp file works correctly if you use a the C++ compiler.

I have try to import the functions inside the class, using `.self()`, also importing it inside the methods of the class, and more things without success. I think this error trace is the nearest time I have been to make it work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `#define RANDOM_CPP` needs to come after `#ifndef RANDOM_CPP` - voting to close as a typo.

Comment: DavidW, I was going to say the same but isn't it odd to have those pre-processor statements in a .cpp file at all?  Shouldn't they be in the header, if anywhere?

Comment: @FiddleStix agreed. It's often a useful shortcut just to include a cpp file directly into a Cython file (if you don't need to share the definitions anywhere), but yes - I wouldn't use include guards there.

Comment: sorry all I did a Typo, because I change my original Class to another more easy to reproduce the error and yes the trace change, I have update my Question

Comment: I resolved my error, Thank you very much @FiddleStix I create .h file defining there my functions and it work!!! Thank you

Comment: I though that I could use it directly without include guards as @DavidW had mention, but seems like Cython need the headers always. Thank you

Comment: @RubialesAlberto If you do the "import the cpp directly" shortcut then don't add it to list list to compile in setup.py as well - you're compiling it twice and that's why you're getting multiple definitions. Using a header file is better though

Comment: Yes now everything goes perfect!